# IKEv2 with EAP-MSCHAPv2 with static IP for each client

Tags: pfsense

I've successfully created an IKEv2 with EAP-MSCHAPv2 VPN for Windows 10 clients using PFSense. This is the link that I followed for doing so: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/IKEv2_with_EAP-MSCHAPv2

The VPN works great but I need to assign to each client a reserved IP address from the virtual pool that I've configured: at this stage the IP address is assigned dynamically and looks like I'm not able to assign a static IP from the client. Considering that I'm using pfsense from the WebGUI, is there a way to make an IP reservation for a specific client or manually assign a static IP in the client?

Maybe I could find something useful from pfsense forum, but at now due to GDPR the forum with all of its contents is offline.

Comment: > Maybe I could find something useful from pfsense forum, but at now due to GDPR the forum with all of its contents is offline. Just to clarify forum is not permanently down, we're migrating to new, GDPR-compliant software base. We expect it back online within the next few hours.